# How to get "COUNT(*)" in Supabase

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I want to retrieve row count in Supabase.

I am guessing it would be something like this:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('cities')
  .select('name', 'COUNT(*)')
```

Is this possible with Supabase?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

<s>For future visitors, we are working on this functionality with the PostgREST maintainer:</s>

<s>https://github.com/supabase/postgrest-js/issues/94</s>

(I'm a maintainer)

This is now released:

```js
const { data, count } = supabase
  .from('countries')
  .select('*', { count: 'exact', head: true })
```

If you want to return the results simultaneously, remove `head`:

```js
const { data, count } = supabase
  .from('countries')
  .select('*', { count: 'exact' })
```

Comment: The count appears to cap out at 1000 (which is the limit for general select calls from the supabase api). Question is if there's a way to get the count without having to make multiple calls on tables with more than a thousand rows?

Comment: It appears now the count func works as expected. There's now a count section in the doc as well, https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select#querying-with-count-option

Comment: But how i can get the count from a foreign table.

Comment: This should be `.select('*', { count: 'exact', head: true })`. Adding `head` only returns row count, which is often what is wanted.

Comment: you forgot to put `await` before the supabase call

Comment: is it possible to count based on status, like group by?

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, you could write a standard Postgres stored procedure or function that returns the count then call that via the SB client.

https://supabase.io/docs/client/rpc

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not supported yet, but there is a [WIP issue](https://github.com/supabase/postgrest-js/issues/94) on Github that would bring this feature to Supabase.

The code below has not been implemented in Supabase yet, but it might look something like this:

```
const { data, error, count } = await supabase
    .from('table')
    .select('*')
    .gt('id', 10)
    .count()
```

Edit 7.19.2021

As kiwicopple has answered, this feature has been added to Supabase with a slightly different form from what I have above. View the accepted answer for more.

Answer (score 0):

## Flutter Solution

```
Future<PostgrestResponse> getCount = await supabase.from('facts').select('id', const FetchOptions(count: CountOption.exact)).eq('type', 'concept').select();
```

Later, access the [count](https://pub.dev/documentation/supabase_flutter/latest/supabase_flutter/PostgrestResponse/count.html) like this:

```
getCount.count
```