# count totalLikes per post with supabase-js

Tags: javascript, sql, supabase

I've been using the supabase-js for my application and I stumbled upon a problem.
I want to get a table like this

| Post | TotalLikes |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | 3 |
| 0002 | 12 |
| 0005 | 0 |

The SQL-query for this would be:

```
SELECT Post, COUNT(*) as TotalLikes from "Votes"
where positive_vote = true
GROUP BY Post
```

I found this stackoverflow: [How to get "COUNT(*)" in Supabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65612167/how-to-get-count-in-supabase)

however this does not help in this case.

Any help/suggestion is welcome

Comment: why didn't it help? errors, it seems quote straight forward

Comment: because here i'm using group by, in his example he just needs 1 row

Comment: yet another framework that has not enough functions, i believe you need https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/rpc to do that

Comment: i know about RPC, however this method is limited and is not suitable for my project.

Comment: why you have a simple select, and supabase, can_'t make t another way. so basically swith framework or use qa procedure, i still don't know why it is not suitable, it gove you a wide range of functions that supabase doesn't have

Comment: because there is a "rate-limit" and also you can have only 10functions per supabase-project. Or I would need to pay 25$ a month, which is something im not aiming for right now

Comment: Tony I think you are confusing edge functions with postgres functions, there are no limits on postgres functions besides your database storage size. You can have more than 10 postgres function (`.rpc`) in your project without needing to pay $25 a month.

Comment: Can you update the question to include what your database schema would look like for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view with this query and then run it using a normal select in the supabase-js library.

Create the view with the following code

```
CREATE VIEW the_name_of_the_view AS
SELECT Post, COUNT(*) as TotalLikes from "Votes"
where positive_vote = true
GROUP BY Post
```

And then call it with

```
await supabase.from('the_name_of_the_view').select('*')
```

Do note that you can't apply row level security (rls) on views in Postgres 14 and below.

Comment: this can help, but imagine if I would like to use an parameter, that wouldn't be possible with views

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a parameter or what that parameter would be.