# How can security can be ensured in this case by Supabase?

Tags: javascript, security, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

When a user in my application claps virtually in the theatre, it will send a request for increasing a count by 1 in Supabase.
Currently, I am using `signInWithPassword` for authentication and the update RLS policy is enabled for authenticated users only.

However, with the approach, the user can open the Chrome console, copy the request headers, including `apikey` and `authentication`, and update the count by sending additional requests, e.g. by using Postman.

What should I do to prevent this? I tried to set the JWT expiration time to 1 sec and successfully acheived the goal, but this solution sounds strange.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a trade-off between simplicity and security.

If you want to make it so that you can limit how many claps a user can send, or how often they can send claps, etc., you have to keep every record of claps that every user sends. You can have a `claps` table that holds `user_id` to hold who clapped, `clapped_at` to hold when the clap happened, and maybe a `post_id` or whatever suites your application to hold what the clap was for. This way, when a user attempts to clap, you can check to see if it's a valid clap or not. Supabase makes it easy to [count rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65612167/how-to-get-count-in-supabase), so getting the total claps isn't a huge issue.

You can use [row level security or RLS](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security) to control how the user can "clap" in your application.

For example, you can set the following RLS policies to allow all users to access the `claps` table, but only allow insert for their own claps. This prevents the users from updating or deleting any claps. You can alter this behavior to whatever suites your application.

```sql
-- Create a sample claps table 
-- This table assumes that there is a `posts` table and a `users` table
create table if not exists public.claps (
    post_id uuid references public.posts on delete cascade not null,
    user_id uuid references public.users on delete cascade not null,
    created_at timestamp with time zone default timezone('utc' :: text, now()) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (post_id, user_id)
);

-- Enable RLS for `claps` table
alter table public.claps enable row level security;

create policy "Any users can view the claps table"
on claps for select
using ( true );

create policy "Allow users to insert their own clap"
on claps for insert
with check ( auth.uid() = user_id );
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Actually what I want is a general solution for this type of replay attack in supabase. Although your solution can ensure the logic runs as expected, user or hacker can still operate the DB outside the program. Thanks.

Comment: @Andy Yes, my suggestion does protect against malicious attacks like those you are concerned with. You have a table `claps` and you create a unique key on `user_id` and `post_id`. That way, each user can only insert a single row per post in the `claps` table. There is nothing the attackers can do to alter that. They can only insert their own claps, or delete a single clap of their own. They have no access to other users claps, or can they alter the total clap count of a post.

Comment: Is any solution can also prevent they amend their own record outside my program? Uuser can access my DB to delete their own record outside my program. I don't think it should be tolerated.

Comment: @Andy You can control how the user can interact with your database with RLS. I have edited my question with some sample snippets, but you should also read the RLS guide from Supabase. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same issue as you .

The only workaround I could think of is to build an API middle layer.
In fact, they are HTTP API on AWS API Gateway + Lambda. This would create a middle layer where you could control the inputs and hide how your backend is working.

Because if an attacker were to discover your supabase query, that's it, reverse engineering becomes straightforward for data leaks or other operations.

PS: I chose HTTP API over REST for performance reasons. Therefore, I cannot implement the Web Application Firewall (WAF) to provide further protection, unless I set up a CloudFront distribution and then WAF. However, this would make the query longer. Currently, the lambda function is written in Python 3.11, very short, only calling supabase. It is deployed in Paris. The supabase is hosted in Frankfurt, so the network distance is optimal.

It takes approximately 450ms to fetch a single entry from supabase and up to 1.9s for 3900 entries (14 columns) on the first run only. Then AWS caches the query and the time goes down to 800ms.

Tested from Supabase, it takes 338ms for the 3900 entries (14 columns) on the first run.
361ms for 1entry